# Box Cloud Annotation Appearance in iText

Tags: annotations, itext, cloud, pdf-generation

This is my sample code to draw a box cloud annotation. I used code in PDFBox's implementation to draw a box cloud but i have a little problem when used in iText. I modified the border class and some parts to be usable in iText.

you can find the border class [here](https://pastebin.com/9tG1JiNs).

My problem is, the top and right border clouds are not drawn. it seems their location is drawn beyond the rect difference. I figure the issue is with drawing the curves in cloudyPolygonImpl(). maybe itext has different ways to draw in PdfAppearance? I am not sure.

This is the what i have so far.
[image: boxcloud]

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("src.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("result.pdf"));

    PdfDictionary be = new PdfDictionary();
    be.put(PdfName.S, PdfName.C);
    be.put(PdfName.I, new PdfNumber(1));

    Rectangle location = new Rectangle(123.6f, 584.4f, 252.6f, 653.4f);
    PdfAnnotation stamp = PdfAnnotation.createSquareCircle(stamper.getWriter(), location, "", true);
    stamp.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(1, PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID));
    stamp.put(new PdfName("BE"), be);
    stamp.setColor(BaseColor.RED);

    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(location.getWidth(), location.getHeight());
    stamp.setAppearance(PdfName.N, app);

    PdfArray stickyRect = stamp.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
    Rectangle annotRect = new Rectangle(stickyRect.getAsNumber(0).floatValue(),
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(1).floatValue(),
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue(),
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(3).floatValue());

    PdfArray arrDiff = annotation.getAsArray(PdfName.RD);
    Rectangle annotRectDiff = null;
    if (arrDiff != null) {
            annotRectDiff = new Rectangle(arrDiff.getAsNumber(0).floatValue(), arrDiff.getAsNumber(1).floatValue(),
        arrDiff.getAsNumber(2).floatValue(), arrDiff.getAsNumber(3).floatValue()
    }

    // Create cloud appearance
    CBorder cborder = new CBorder(app, 1, 1, annotRect);
    cborder.createCloudyRectangle(annotRectDiff);

    stamp.put(PdfName.RECT, new PdfRectangle(cborder.getRectangle()));
    stamp.put(PdfName.RD, new PdfArray(new float[] { 
        cborder.getRectDifference().getLeft(), 
        cborder.getRectDifference().getBottom(), 
        cborder.getRectDifference().getRight(), 
        cborder.getRectDifference().getTop() }));

    app.rectangle(cborder.getBBox());
    app.transform(cborder.getMatrix());


    app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
    app.setLineWidth(1);
    app.stroke();

    stamper.addAnnotation(stamp, 1);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}    
    }
```

The correct output should be that all borders be drawn with cloud but currently only the left and bottom are drawn.

Comment: You called `cborder.createCloudyRectangle(null);` while the PDFBox PDSquareAppearanceHandler.java called `cloudyBorder.createCloudyRectangle(annotation.getRectDifference());`. PDFBox also modifies the annotation rectangle after the clouds are done. (Adobe Reader also does this IIRC)

Comment: Hi tilman. yes. was experimenting with the code but the result is the same since getRectDifference() returns null even in pdfbox and even when i used that method instead of just null, the resulting appearance is the same. i will change back the code.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr the rectangle values are the same as the values in PDFBox. I figure the issue may be within cloudyPolygonImpl() of the border class. it may be different in iText with regards to how it is drawn.

Comment: Your recent edit is weird, it introduces a new variable `annotation` which is defined nowhere, and the code in the new `if (arrDiff != null)` block is syntactically broken. Thus, I'll answer based on the original code.

Comment: As an aside: Your code appears to have issues with page rotation by 90° or 270°...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This answer is based on the code in [revision 3 of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56388137/3) as the changes in [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56388137/4) introduced multiple errors.)*

Your code here creates an invalid annotation appearance stream:

```java
CBorder cborder = new CBorder(app, 1, 1, annotRect);
cborder.createCloudyRectangle(null);

stamp.put(PdfName.RECT, new PdfRectangle(cborder.getRectangle()));
stamp.put(PdfName.RD, new PdfArray(new float[] { 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getLeft(), 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getBottom(), 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getRight(), 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getTop() }));

app.rectangle(cborder.getBBox());
app.transform(cborder.getMatrix());


app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
app.setLineWidth(1);
app.stroke();
```

Its upper part creates a path:

```
2 j
121.58 588.63 m
122.06 588.95 122.6 589.18 123.16 589.3 c
120.73 588.78 119.18 586.4 119.7 583.96 c
120.19 581.67 122.35 580.14 124.68 580.44 c
...
122.06 596.42 122.6 596.64 123.16 596.76 c
121.09 596.32 119.6 594.49 119.6 592.36 c
119.6 590.87 120.34 589.47 121.58 588.63 c
h
```

Then `app.rectangle(cborder.getBBox())` does not create anything (beware, this `rectangle` overload does not what you expect it to do!).

Then `app.transform(cborder.getMatrix())` adds a change to the current transformation matrix, `app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED)` adds a change of the stroking color, and `app.setLineWidth(1)` adds a change of the line width:

```
1 0 0 1 -118.68 -579.48 cm
1 0 0 RG
1 w
```

And finally `app.stroke()` adds the command to stroke the path:

```
S
```

But between the definition of a path and the corresponding path drawing command, only clipping path instructions are allowed! Cf. Figure 9 – Graphics Objects – in the PDF specification ISO 32000-1.

You can fix this code like this, pulling up color and line width changes, and directly using the cloud bounding box:

```java
// Create cloud appearance
app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
app.setLineWidth(1);

CBorder cborder = new CBorder(app, 1, 1, annotRect);
cborder.createCloudyRectangle(null);

stamp.put(PdfName.RECT, new PdfRectangle(cborder.getRectangle()));
stamp.put(PdfName.RD, new PdfArray(new float[] { 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getLeft(), 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getBottom(), 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getRight(), 
    cborder.getRectDifference().getTop() }));

app.stroke();
app.setBoundingBox(cborder.getBBox());
```

*([CloudBoxAnnotation](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/CloudBoxAnnotation.java#L108) test `testDrawLikeChitgoksImproved`)*

This in particular changes the result (as seen in Adobe Acrobat) from

[image: Screenshot original]

to

[image: Screenshot fix]

Comment: it works! Though i thought doing it the same way as PDFBox would do the trick. I was surprised about not having to use cs.rectangle() and cs.transform(). The same way you did it to draw cloud annotation does the trick as well. thank you!

Comment: @chitgoks well, your original approach tried to move the appearance to match a previously set annotation appearance boundary box value. My approach changed the annotation appearance boundary box value to match the unmoved appearance. Either approach can work.